# Bounded Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to put together a step of an implication problem:

L-1 < Sn < L+1 implies |Sn| < |L| + 1

I am not following how to get this conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

$L-1 < S_n < L+1$ is equivalent to $|S_n-L|<1$. From the triangle inequality obtain $$|S_n|-|L|\leq |S_n-L|<1,$$ from which you get $|S_n|<|L|+1$.

Comment: Ahh, the triangle inequality.  Thank you!

Comment: Could you please show me the calculations?  I am getting stuck somewhere.

Comment: Which specific step in calculations?

Comment: Here is what I have so far

Comment: |Sn| < |Sn-L| + |L| < |L| + 1

Comment: I think you showed what you you wanted, didn't you?

Comment: The only correction I'd make is $S_n \leq |S_n-L|+|L|$ (not the strict inequality you have)

Comment: Oh, can I break up |Sn-L| in the middle?

Comment: Why would you want to break it up? I thought it was given that $|S_n-L|<1$.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it.